# Powershell script to Get-Process then prompt for input of ID for Stop-Process

Tags: powershell

I have two Powershell commands that I'd like to create a script with.  I've searched for a while and can't seem to find anything similar to what I need. I need to ask for input (Id) for the second command, after being able to view the processes from the first command. The process I need to kill will not always be the same, hence the need for input on which one to kill.

1. Get-Process -Computername *computername*
2. Stop-Process -ComputerName *computername* -Id #### -Confirm -PassThru

I greatly appreciate any info I receive.

Comment: Are you using Windows PowerShell? `Get-Process -ComputerName ... |Out-GridView -PassThru |Stop-Process -ComputerName ...` might be an option

Comment: When using `Out-Gridview`, don't forget to supply an informative `-Title` to make it clear what's going to happen to the poor processes.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am using Windows PowerShell.  I'll definitely try this!